# How to check what was installed by Windows Automatic Maintenance?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-update, windows-8.1, maintenance

Windows Automatic Maintenance (on windows 8.1) just finished and during about 2 hours it consumed 6GB of disc space (which is very valuable as I have 128GB SSD only). How can I check what it installed or what did it do with my disc space (maybe some backups, restore points, etc)? It's hard to believe it just downloaded 6GB worth of updates to a system that is less than 2 weeks old...

Is there any way to get a report of what was done by each maintenance session?

Comment: in general automatic maintenance wont install/backup anything,it was just an process where it will involve Deadline scheduling
Resource utilization conflicts
Energy efficiency
Transparency to the user,http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx there wont be no backup's or installation will be done during the maintenance process

Comment: So still the question remains: what happened with 6GB of space...

Comment: does viewing update history doesnt work?which will list all updates done during windows update,check whether any windows update occured at that time